# converting varchar time stored in oracle databse to time ? and roudoff seconds of it?

Tags: oracle, datetime

I want to convert time which is stored as a VARCHAR in database into datetime and then roundoff the seconds into minutes. right now i have record as "01:57:45" in my database as VARCHAR datatype and i want to convert it into Datetime and then roundoff the seconds part of time.
Please kindly help me,
i have written the following query just to retrieve time which is in VARCHAR form. Please give me solution for the same

```
SELECT WORK_COMPLETION_TIME FROM WORKASSIGNMENT
```

Comment: Is the WORK_COMPLETION_TIME column the time at which the work was completed (ie. will never be more than 24 hours) or is it the length of time it took to complete the work? If the former, you should be storing it as a DATE field, along with the date at which the work was completed. E.g. `to_date('04/03/2016 01:57:45', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: What date do you want the converted value to have? Or do you just want it back as a string but rounded, e.g. as `'01:58:00'`?

Comment: i just want it back as string but with rounded off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it as the time (rounded to the nearest minute) for today's date then:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE WorkAssignment( Work_Completion_Time ) AS
SELECT '01:57:45' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ROUND(
        TO_DATE(
          TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD' ) || Work_Completion_Time,
          'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS'
         ),
        'MI'
       ) AS rounded_time
FROM   WorkAssignment
```

**Output**:

*(The format depends on your NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings as it is returning a `DATE`)*

```
ROUNDED_TIME
-------------------
2016-03-04 01:58:00
```

**Query - Just return the rounded time string**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         ROUND(
           TO_DATE( Work_Completion_Time, 'HH24:MI:SS' ),
           'MI'
         ),
         'HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS rounded_time
FROM   WorkAssignment
```

**Output**:

```
ROUNDED_TIME
------------
01:58:00
```

Comment: giving me an error as 'Unsupported Column aliasing'

Comment: @suhas Updated - you didn't mention that you were on 10G or earlier.